# How to test postgresql statement timeout config in rails database.yml?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, timeout, minitest, postgresql-11

I am in need of adding some test suite for asserting Rails `database.yml` configuration. I have configured db statement timeout to 2000ms, I need a way to assert that the configuration is working through a test case.

There are 2 ways to test:

1. Verify that database.yml statement timeout is configured to 2500ms but not checking if configuration is working or not ?
2. Issue a sql a statement that takes more than 2500ms and assert there is a exception raised.

```rb
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(<<~SQL)
  select pg_sleep(86400);
SQL
```

This code will raise the exception but actually executes for 2500ms to raise the exception, So I need a way to assert this without waiting for
2500ms.

```rb
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(<<~SQL)
  select pg_sleep(86400);
SQL
```

Answer (score 0):

By definition, there is no way to test that a timeout is working without waiting for that timeout.

What you could do, is set a much smaller timeout value *specifically* for your test environment (let's say, 500ms) and assert the exception is raised after you sleep for 600ms.